# Calling onlogin even for authenticated email

Tags: openid, browserid

I want to try Mozilla Persona in my recent project but found one unpleasant feature.

I hardcoded email-address in navigator.id.watch like this:

```js
navigator.id.watch({
    loggedInUser: "vansanblch@gmail.com",
    onlogin: function () {
        console.log("onlogin");
    },
    onlogout: function () {
        console.log("onlogout");
    },
});
```

Then I call `navigator.id.request()` and enter my credentials to pass authentication. In developers API ([about navigator.id.watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/navigator.id.watch)) it is said that if loggedInUser equal to 
state from Persona then no callbacks will be called.

But why I have "onlogin" message in console every single time I call `navigator.id.request()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening because you found a corner case that Persona isn't handling. Oops.

The Persona team needs to sit down and figure out what *should* happen when you do that. I've filed a bug to track that discussion: https://github.com/mozilla/browserid/issues/3332

I'd appreciate it if you could chime in with what you think the correct behavior should be, and why.

For context, Persona initially used `loggedInUser` only for determining what callbacks to invoke automatically during page load. After that, it was more or less ignored. Which is why you're seeing calls to `onlogin`, even though the selected identity matches the current identity.